# EF Core 3.1 Add Unique Contraints to a Navigator

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have the a Error "'Class1' cannot be used as a property on entity type 'Class2' because it is configured as a navigation." when using add migration.

I cant add a Unique Contraint at a Navigator property.

Using EF Core 3.1

Class1:

```
public class Class1
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Class1Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime ExtractedDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual ICollection<Class2> Class2Id { get; set; }

    }
```

Class2:

```
 public class Class2
        {
            [Key]
            [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            public int Class2Id { get; set; }

            [MaxLength(256)]
            public string LicenceKey { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public Class1 Class1Id { get; set; }        
        }
```

Here is my Dbcontext class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            //Property Configurations
            modelBuilder.Entity<Class1>()
                .HasMany(c => c.Class2Id)
                .WithOne(e => e.Class1Id);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Class1>()
                .HasIndex(ir => ir.ExtractedDate)
                .IsUnique();

            modelBuilder.Entity<Class2>()
                .HasIndex(ir => new {ir.Class1Id, ir.LicenceKey})
                .IsUnique();
}
```

Is there a way that i can declare the Contraints with the Navigators? or if there is another way?

I tryed also Using SQL Connection and manually adding the Constrains after the tables was created and it works. But then im not using fully the EF Core.

Comment: `Class1Id` should be an `int`, paired with a reference navigation property `Class1`.

Comment: can you please elaborate it or can you like post here a code sample?